# Argument about the size of Frobenius kernel, question on derivation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

The following discussion is from the textbook *Finite Group Theory* by Kurzweil and Stellmacher:

> Let $G$ be a permutation group on $\Omega$ and $|\Omega| > 1$. Then $G$ is a **Frobenius group** on $\Omega$ if
>
> - $G$ acts transitively on $\Omega$,
> - $G_{\alpha} \ne 1$ for any $\alpha \in G$,
> - $G_{\alpha} \cap G_{\beta} = 1$ for all $\alpha, \beta \in \Omega, \alpha \ne \beta$.
>
> Let $G$ be a Frobenius group on $\Omega$, and $H := G_{\alpha}$. The transitive action of $G$ on $\Omega$ gives $\{ H^g : g \in G \} = \{ G_{\beta} : \beta \in \Omega \}$, and $F := G \setminus \bigcup_{g\in G} H^g$ is the set of elements of $G$ that do not have any fixed point in $\Omega$. Let $K := F \cup \{ 1_G \}$. Then 
>   $$
>  (*) \quad G^{\#} = K^{\#} \cup \bigcup_{g\in G} (H^g)^{\#}
> $$
>   is a partion of $G^{\#}$ ($G^{\#}$ denotes the group element without the identity). Then
>   $|\Omega| = |K|$ as with (*)
>   $$
>  |K| = |G| - |G:H|(|H| - 1)
> $$
>   which implies the claim.

In the last equation they use that $|G:H|$ denotes the number of conjugates of $H$, but how do they know that? Later, they give an internal characterisation of Frobenius groups by groups with a non-trivial subgroup such that $H\cap H^g = 1$ for each $g \notin H$, which implies $N_G(H) = H$ and therefore that $|G:H|$ denotes the number of conjugates of $H$, but how do they know this up to this point? I do not see the argument. As I see it $|G:H| = |G:G_{\alpha}| = |\alpha^G| = |\Omega|$, but this is all I can see about the index up to this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you *sure* you don't know that there are exactly $|G:H|$ conjugates of $H = G_\alpha$?

In particular, in the proof they write that $\{H^g: g \in G\} = \{G_\beta: \beta \in \Omega\}$. The set on the left is the set of all conjugates of $H = G_\alpha$, and the set on the right has cardinality $\Omega$. If you've agreed with this, and the fact you pointed out that that $|G:H| = |\Omega|$, then you do know that $|G:H|$ counts the number of conjugates of $H = G_\alpha$.

If you're not convinced that those two sets are equal, it's fairly straightforward to show that, given a transitive action of a group $G$ on a set $\Omega$, all stabilizer subgroups are conjugate.

I think this is all you need, but feel free to ask for any more details.